# How do I set up a sharepoint discussion board so the new discussions must be approved before they are public?

Tags: discussion-board

I need to set up a discussion board for product tech info. The discussion must be reviewed by a product specialist before it can be made public to sales staff for replies.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the list settings and set the content approval option to Yes in the Versioning Settings.

Comment: Then you might want to mark the response as answered and/or upvote the answer.